# Router is not defined in index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So basically this is my index.js file and

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

And this is the app.js file

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Default from "./components/Default.js"
import {Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <Switch>          
          <Route path='/' component={Default}/>
        </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am getting Router not defined when I run it on browser.But I have already installed router using npm install react-router

Comment: You need to import it as well, of course.

Comment: I tried this 
import { browserHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router';

but this throws so many errors if i import it inindex.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing import for `Router`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

// missing import
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```